# Ionic 4 (not capacitor) build failed with @firebase/logger error [TS1068: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context]

Tags: angular, firebase, logging, ionic4

Ionic build is failing after adding `firebase` and `@angular/fire` to my project. I have been using firebase and angularFire for ages, but suddenly this issue came up at build.

Seems to be with a file `logger.d.ts` related issue, however, I am not even using firebase's Logger. Must be some inside call, searched web for hours but could not find an answer, hopefully someone might have come across this issue earlier? can shed some light?

below is the error message image

[image]

```
> ng run app:build

ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/src/logger.d.ts:70:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

70     get logLevel(): LogLevel;
           ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/src/logger.d.ts:71:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

71     set logLevel(val: LogLevel);
           ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/src/logger.d.ts:77:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

77     get logHandler(): LogHandler;
           ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/src/logger.d.ts:78:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

78     set logHandler(val: LogHandler);
           ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/src/logger.d.ts:83:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

83     get userLogHandler(): LogHandler | null;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/src/logger.d.ts:84:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

84     set userLogHandler(val: LogHandler | null);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

        ng run app:build exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

My package.json looks like the following

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.13.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "npm-force-resolutions": "0.0.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
```

Please help if someone can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

You need to use TypeScript 3.7.
From TypeScript 3.7 [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) :

> To detect the issue around accessors, TypeScript 3.7 will now emit get/set accessors in .d.ts files so that in TypeScript can check for overridden accessors.

So you'll need to either upgrade to TypeScript 3.7 or use an earlier version of `Firebase`.

### Solution 2

Set `skipLibCheck` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  ...
}
```

Comment: you are a life saver man, Solution 2 worked for me just fine. Thx

Comment: Thank you, correct explanation and solutions. I just thrown away half day in trying different dependencies version matchings, and for a quick resolution your second solution works great.

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting this when trying to upgrade my firebase package from 7.11.0 and up. Try fixing the firebase version to 7.11.0.

As for a real long term solution, I am also interested.

Comment: unfortunately din work at my end. I removed the node_module folder, deleted package-lock.json file, changed the firebase version to 7.11.0, and run npm install, but same errors like up there :(

I will try n remove other plugins and see if anything else is inferring, with the packages !!! will update my findings here

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with Ionic 4, I've downgraded Firebase to 7.10.

Can't use Typescript > 3.6 with Angular 8, or raises `ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.8.3 was found instead.`

I didn't try to toggle `skipLibCheck` compiler option, doesn't seem a long term solution.

By the way, thanks all for the thread, save my day ;-)